# How to check if DbMappingViewCache caches the precompiled views

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-standard

I'm building a AWS Lambda with dotnet core 3.1 and testing it out locally

To improve performance i wanted to precompile the views following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/pre-generated-views

I have created my own `DbMappingViewCache` called `DbMappingViewCacheImp` and hooked it up with `[assembly: DbMappingViewCacheType(typeof(MyContext), typeof(AWSLambda1.DbMappingViewCacheImp))]`

But when im debugging and trying to see what happens, the code in `public override DbMappingView GetView(EntitySetBase extent)` never fire and i can see on the execution time that it builds the views on the first query

Am I missing something here?

I'm adding this class (not actual implementation) in my AWS Lambda function with `[assembly: DbMappingViewCacheType(typeof(MyContext), typeof(AWSLambda1.DbMappingViewCacheImp))]`

I put breakpoints in `MappingHashValue` and `GetView` but neither will get hit

```
public class DbMappingViewCacheImp : DbMappingViewCache
{
    public override string MappingHashValue => "";

    public override DbMappingView GetView(EntitySetBase extent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to move my cache from the Domain project (where my EF4 EntityViewContainer was) to my Data project where the UnitOfWork : DbContext lives.  Then it started working, i.e. hits breakpoint in `GetView`.